# How can I change number of rows in Ubuntu server terminal

Tags: linux

I use server version of Ubuntu, and I can't find out how to change the number of rows in terminal. I mean I want to scroll back in terminal a lot more rows than the default. I can't make it via GUI like in desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
$ screen -h 5000
```

That should increase the buffer to 5000 lines.